# Is there a way to click a <td> element where both id and name is present using vba ( it is a search button)

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to click a button through VBA. Inspect element shows this:

```
    </td>
<input name="btnSearch" id="btnSearch" style="width: 150px;" type="submit" value="Search">
```

I have tried the below code. I am able to click the element `tdocs` but not able to click on the click `btnSearch` .

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLAs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLA As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim SearchButton As Object
    Dim tdocs As Object
    Dim elements As Object
    Dim element As Object          

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://portal.3gpp.org/#55931-tdocs"

    Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

    Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document
    Set tdocs = HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("lt-55931-tdocs")
    tdocs(0).Click

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))'03sec

    Set elements = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each element In elements
        On Error Resume Next 
        If element.ID = "btnSearch" Then
            element.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next element
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 of things

1. Use ids throughout as faster
2. Use a condition based wait after first click (in this case I wait for the parent `li` class name to change indicating the tab of interest is now active)
3. To click on the next element of interest you need to navigate the parent iframe
4. Modern browsers (:laughs in the face of IE!) are optimized for [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) so use those with [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector))

VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PerformClicks()
    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://portal.3gpp.org/#/55931-tdocs"

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document.querySelector("#ui-id-2") 'use id as faster
            .Click
            Do
            Loop Until InStr(.ParentNode.className, "ui-tabs-active") > 0 'Loop until tab becomes active
        End With
        'handle iframe
        .document.querySelector("#dnn_ctr559_View_ctl00_ctl01_ctr596_ETSIFrame_htmModule").contentDocument.querySelector("#btnSearch").Click
        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Delete the Stop line later. It is there so you can observe changes on page.

Comment: I haven't worked with query selector yet and If possible could you please tell how we would copy the data using the same

Comment: hi, what do you mean by copy the data please?

Comment: I mean when i run your solution the page shows some of the results. And i want to copy the results and paste in the excel sheet

Comment: ok... if you open a new question and include your attempt I will have a look. For understanding querySelector you simply place the css selector within the "" i.e. querySelector("css selector")  or  querySelectorAll("css selector") . To understand pattern matching see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: Hey , Can you check it now ? < https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58055951/is-there-a-way-to-download-a-row-of-a-table-or-an-entire-table-itself-on-a-webpa >