# is there a way to download a row of a table or an entire table itself on a webpage using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I am able to download the inner text but not the exact table

I have tried using inner text and it only gave the text of the entire row

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
        Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
        Dim HTMLAs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
        Dim HTMLA As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

        Dim tdocs As Object

        Dim iframeDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

        IE.Visible = True
        IE.navigate "https://portal.3gpp.org/#55931-tdocs"



        Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Loop

        Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document

        Set tdocs = HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("lt-55931-tdocs")
        tdocs(0).Click

       Set iframeDoc = HTMLDoc.frames("dnn_ctr559_View_ctl00_ctl01_ctr596_ETSIFrame_htmModule").Document

Dim img As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Set img = iframeDoc.getElementById("btnSearch")
    img.Click

   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:59")) '30sec
End If

For i = 1 To 2000
 Set img = iframeDoc.getElementById("rgTdocList_ctl00__" & i)

 Range("A" & i) = img.innerText

    End Sub
```

I am getting the row in one column but i want them to be how it is originally on the web page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
'...
'...
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:30")) '30sec

Dim tds, x

For i = 1 To 2000
    Set img = iframeDoc.getElementById("rgTdocList_ctl00__" & i)
    If img Is Nothing Then Exit For 'no more rows
    Set tds = img.getElementsByTagName("td") '<< get cells for this row
    'write out each cell's content
    For x = 0 To tds.Length - 1
        Cells(i, x + 1) = tds(x).innerText
    Next x
Next i
```